# Does Dragon's Dogma: Dark Arisen come with all of the original DLC?

Tags: dragons-dogma, dragons-dogma-dark-arisen

I was looking at the list of DLC for Dragons Dogma [here](https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/en-au/games/dragon%27s-dogma/cid=EP0102-BLES01356_00-DISCONLYPARENT00%3AADD-ONS) and was comparing it to the DLC for [Dragons Dogma: Dark Arisen](https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/en-au/games/dragon%27s-dogma-dark-arisen/cid=EP0102-NPEB01268_00-DDDA000000000000) but there is a huge difference in what's available.

To my understanding Dark Arisen is just Dragons Dogma with another story line added in which can be played afterwords. So I am wondering, is all of the DLC for Dragons Dogma already in Dragons Dogma: Dark Arisen? (kinda like with Disgaea 3 on PS Vita has all the PS3 DLC already in it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [blog post](http://www.capcom-unity.com/gregaman/blog/2013/05/01/psa-dragons-dogma-dlc-questions-answered) from Capcom's site states that yes it does.

Note that to get the other freebies in DD:DA you need to import a save from the original Dragon's Dogma, but it can be one where you only made a character and didn't play past the first save point.

Edited to add that this post refers to the console version. The PC version does come will all of the DLC but the character import portion of this answer doesn't apply to the PC version of the game.